# Scaling doesn't take?

Tags: gimp, resize

I'm trying to scale my image down without messing up the text, so I did this:

[image: Scale attempt.]

Wherein I increased the resolution and decreased the height.

Well, as you can see, the height is 2 inches in the dialog; however, in my printout, the height is about 5-6 inches.  It's a noticeable difference.  It's very important that the image only be 2 inches in height and locked in width.  What are the limits to the resolution before it starts overwriting the height-width restrictions?  Seems like a bug?

Comment: Hi Wolfpack, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: If you are printing from GIMP, then note that the print dialog allows to adjust the printed size as well.

Comment: It's interesting. [this video](https://youtu.be/uvnSL-e9-Nw), at around 1:20, indicates that scaling does change the size. But I suffer the same problem - the resolution changes but not the size.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it seems a little screwed up. You can go to Image>Print Size and change the resolution to the value you want. This doesn't change the size of the image just the dpi setting (which will affect the print size). Then scale the image to the size you want but don't change the resolution settings. If scale image doesn't work go to Image>Canvas Size to resize. Select "all layers" under resize layers and click the center button before resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Because as shown in the dialog, your image is 2 inches if you print it at 1374PPI. The figure you give hints that it is printed at 600DPI which could be the maximum that your print driver allows.

If you want the image to be 2" high at 600DPI, then scale it to 1200 pixels high.

Another solution is to export the image, open a word processor, insert the image and set its dimensions in the word processor, and print the page from the word processor.

PS: with text, it is normally a good idea to work at the right size for the start, the 30px font isn't exactly a half-size 60px font, smaller fonts have subtle changes to improve readability. Since Gimp is a bitmap editor, this kind of information is lost and when text is scaled down (later in Gimp or in the print driver) your small print is less legible.

Answer (score -3):

It's because GIMP doesn't work. You can do this for all image sizes from scale, print size and canvas for all layers. The image can be configured to print correctly but won't allow you to export said image to JPG or another format like PNG in a scaled image size.

It'll say it's 5" for a print in 5" but when you export said image it won't adhere this change and then be in a much larger format like 10" instead of 5" because GIMP doesn't work at all and guides all claim it does but it's a software defect/bug.